# Deploying exploded multi-module project with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven-module "web-app" with packaging type `war` (JSF-application). It has a dependency to another module "core" of the same project with packaging type `jar`. This jar contains as well Java-classes as resources (js or xhtml-Files).

Now I configure in IntelliJ 2016.3 a deployment on JBoss using an exploded version of the web-app. But the module "core" does not get exploded as well, so I cannot perform a hot deployment on the resources of the core. But: Hot deployment of classes work.

I already tried some modifications on the webapp-artifact:
When adding "core compile output" to `WEB-INF/classes` my JBoss booted, but it could not find any resources.
When adding "core compile output" to WEB-INF/lib not surrounded by a jar, I get a bunch of ClassNotFound-Exceptions.

I attached the current configuration of the artifact:
[image]

Do you have an idea how I can hot deploy my resources again?

-- edit

When packaging the project using maven the `web-app/target`-folder contains all dependencies as jars.
After CrazyCoders comment of using the maven-resources-plugin I added to the `pom.xml` of the web-app following snippet:

```
# web-app/pom.xml
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>../core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Now the resources are in the `web-app/target`-folder! For example the file search.xhtml is located in following locations:

```
1. web-app/target/classes/app/search/search.xhtml
2. web-app/target/<finalName>/WEB-INF/classes/app/search/search.xhtml
```

and packed inside following jars:

```
3. web-app/target/<finalName>/WEB-INF/lib/core-1.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
4. core/target/core.jar
```

When I change `search.xhtml` and click "update resources" in IntelliJ IDEA, only the files 1., 2. and 3. change, but not 4.

On reload still nothing happens. In the screenshot above there was configured that IntelliJ should use `core-1.11.0-SNAPSHOT` and not `core.jar`. Or is there something else why these resources don't get updated?

Comment: Are you sure `core` compile output contains all the required files? Check the output directory on disk.

Comment: Yes, it contains all .cass-files but no resource-files like css or js.

Comment: So, the problem is caused by the missing resources in the compile output of the module?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Meanwhile I found a solution for the similar problem when using an ear (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/unpacking-a-module.html). But I found nothing like this in the maven-war-plugin...

Comment: Where do you keep the resources in the core module? You can adjust Maven configuration so that it correctly treats this directory as resources, in this case IntelliJ IDEA should also copy the resource files to the output.

Comment: I keep it in resources/META-INF/resources. How can I configure Maven to treat this directory as resources? Sounds interesting!

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: Thank you, CrazyCoder. I tried it and it feels better, but still does not work. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a problem I have been struggling with the last few days.  The problem is that Intellij is not using Maven to build the module.  It is just doing a simple compile.  So the jar does not get packaged properly.  My workaround was to remove the module's entry from the lib node, replacing it with a new entry using Add Copy of | File, pointing it to the jar file in the module's target folder.  Having done that, I also needed to add a Run Maven Goal to the configuration to do a "clean package" before building the war artifact.